# Can not edit video in rails by using edit/update button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a Rails newbie and trying to code a rails website which one can upload a video and edit it ofcourse.

At first, I follow Rails example and successfully upload a video, very nice.

My problem is, I make an edit button, like this button.[Update button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHTy7.png)

I upload some videos to `wistia.com`, and paste the words after `medias` to `video`. For example, the link is `https://anhbui2904.wistia.com/medias/6ixv9su5ii` then I copy and paste `6ixv9su5ii` to the blank `video`

What I want is, when I push the `update course`, the video will change. But nothing changed.

Here is my code at `app/views/courses/show.html.erb`

```
  <div class="card-image">
    <iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/avk9twrrbn" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="100%" height="349"></iframe>
    <script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script> 
  </div>
```

I used this code to display a video.

Could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: Should that url not be a public url? I am unable to see the video, this might be the reason you are not seeing it either? (it seems now it is only visible to the owner of the video or logged in users on wistia?)

Comment: @nathanvda sorry for the link, I update the link and I think that my url is a public url ? Any idea for me ?

Comment: Show some more code: how do you save the video-field? Is it saved correctly? Is the shown code for `show.html.erb` exact, or did you show the rendered html? Please show us the contents of the `show.html.erb` view (because now the video url seems hardcoded).

Comment: Please share your controller and model and also the saving logs from the rails log file (from the log folder)

Comment: @nathanvda I thought that the rest of the code of `show.html.erb` was not important so I did not show them, but here are they, I uses them to show an image.

`<div class="card-content white-text">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col m4 center">
           <%= image_tag ("courses/1.png"), class: "img-responsive"%> 
           </div> 
           <div class="col m8">
          <span class="card-title"><%= @course.title %></span>
          <p><%= @course.description %></p>   
         </div> 
        </div>
       </div>`

Comment: This question looks very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306805/rails-how-to-embed-a-wistia-video-dynamically-through-a-form

Answer (score 0):

In your `show.html.erb` you now have url hard-coded, you should make sure the `src` uses your `@course.video` field. You could do this as follows:

```
<iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/#{#course.video}" allowtransparency=...
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. I changed my code just from `avk9twrrbn` to `#{#course.video}"` and still can not post my video, here is my page when I changed it. <https://postimg.cc/Wq37q6vC> Any ideas for me?